# How to apply css to link in dropdown table using arrow keys and hover event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a beginner web developer and I'm trying to enable selection in a search results dropdown using the up and down keys. Previously it was only working with a mouse, so you had to hover over the search result with the mouse and then click on the link you were interested in. So far I've been able to apply my css class to the result row in the table, but once I release the up or down key the css reverts to the default. This is my code so far:

Hover css:

```
.search .results a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-color: #2380dd #2179d5 #1a60aa;
    background-color: #338cdf;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #59aaf4), color-stop(100%, #338cdf));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
```

Highlight css:

```
.highlight {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-color: #2380dd #2179d5 #1a60aa;
    background-color: #338cdf;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #59aaf4), color-stop(100%, #338cdf));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
```

Keydown handler:

```
var current_row = -1;
var up = 38;
var down = 40;

$("#sinput").keydown(function (e) {

    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case down:
            var links = $(".results").find("a");

            if (current_row < links.length) {
                links.eq(current_row).removeClass();
                current_row++;
            }

            //links.eq(current_row).removeClass("hover");
            links.eq(current_row).addClass("highlight");
            break;

        case up:
            var links = $(".results").find("a");

            if (current_row > 0) {
                links.eq(current_row).removeClass();
                current_row--;
            }

            //links.eq(current_row).removeClass("hover");
            links.eq(current_row).addClass("highlight");
            break;
    }
    return true;
});
```

I thought perhaps the hover class was interfering with my highlight class (which should not depend on the mouseover event) so I tried removing it. However this does not work. The highlight appears but as soon as I release the up/down key it goes away. Why might this be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to reduce your code to the bare minimum and to me it looks like the JavaScript is working just fine (except that `current_row < links.length` should be `current_row < links.length - 1`).

```js
var current_row = -1;
var up = 38;
var down = 40;

$("#sinput").keydown(function (e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case down:
      var links = $(".results").find("a");

      if (current_row < links.length - 1)
      {
        links.eq(current_row).removeClass();
        current_row++;
      }

      links.eq(current_row).addClass("highlight");
      break;
    case up:
      var links = $(".results").find("a");

      if (current_row > 0)
      {
        links.eq(current_row).removeClass();
        current_row--;
      }

      links.eq(current_row).addClass("highlight");
      break;
  }
  return true;
});
```

```css
.search .results a:hover {
  color: red;
}

.highlight {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="search">
  <input type="text" id="sinput" />
  <ul class="results">
    <li><a>Foo</a></li>
    <li><a>Bar</a></li>
    <li><a>Baz</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Original theory:** What's probably causing the problem is that `.highlight` is an relatively short selector and in CSS the rule with the longest selector takes precedence.

If you have a rule `.search .results a` which sets the default style of the result items it overwrites the properties in `.highlight`.
The example below is therefore not working.

```js
var current_row = -1;
var up = 38;
var down = 40;

$("#sinput").keydown(function (e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case down:
      var links = $(".results").find("a");

      if (current_row < links.length - 1)
      {
        links.eq(current_row).removeClass();
        current_row++;
      }

      links.eq(current_row).addClass("highlight");
      break;
    case up:
      var links = $(".results").find("a");

      if (current_row > 0)
      {
        links.eq(current_row).removeClass();
        current_row--;
      }

      links.eq(current_row).addClass("highlight");
      break;
  }
  return true;
});
```

```css
.search .results a {
  color: gray;
}

.search .results a:hover {
  color: red;
}

.highlight {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="search">
  <input type="text" id="sinput" />
  <ul class="results">
    <li><a>Foo</a></li>
    <li><a>Bar</a></li>
    <li><a>Baz</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If this is the case you just have to be more specific in the declaration of `.highlight` to solve the problem:

```js
var current_row = -1;
var up = 38;
var down = 40;

$("#sinput").keydown(function (e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case down:
      var links = $(".results").find("a");

      if (current_row < links.length - 1)
      {
        links.eq(current_row).removeClass();
        current_row++;
      }

      links.eq(current_row).addClass("highlight");
      break;
    case up:
      var links = $(".results").find("a");

      if (current_row > 0)
      {
        links.eq(current_row).removeClass();
        current_row--;
      }

      links.eq(current_row).addClass("highlight");
      break;
  }
  return true;
});
```

```css
.search .results a {
  color: gray;
}

.search .results a:hover {
  color: red;
}

.search .results a.highlight {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="search">
  <input type="text" id="sinput" />
  <ul class="results">
    <li><a>Foo</a></li>
    <li><a>Bar</a></li>
    <li><a>Baz</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Actual solution:** A `keyup` listener, which generates the search results, could cause the issue: when the up/down key is released the results are regenerated and overwrite the existing results (And therefore the `highlight` class). You could try to return from the `keyup` handler if `e.keyCode` is `up` or `down` or listen for `input` events instead (Which are fired only when the input actually changes): `$("#sinput").on("input", function(e) { ... })`

Comment: I added the .search .results in front of my highlight declaration, but the search results still do not stay with the highlight. Here's my current declaration: `.search .results a.highlight`

Comment: I noticed the links are in a list (li). So should my declaration be something like `.search .results li a.highlight`? I tried just that but it did not seem to work.

Comment: Sounds like my theory has been wrong and the problem is not related to the length of the selector.  Do you have a `keyup` listener or do you toggle the `highlight` class in JavaScript somewhere else? Can you confirm, that the class is set when you release the key (e.g. Using `Inspect Element`)?

Comment: I do have a keyup listener, in which the search results are generated.

Comment: It could be possible that when the up/down key is released the results are regenerated and overwrite the existing results (And therefore the `highlight` class). You could try to return from the `keyup` handler if `e.keyCode` is `up` or `down` or listen for `input` events instead (Which are fired only when the input actually changes): `$("#sinput").on("input", function(e) { ... })`

Comment: Turns out the results were being regenerated *after* I had applied the highlight class. D'oh!